# How do I mange image placement in Lyx?

Tags: pdf, lyx

I am new to Lyx and used the tutorial but i have never used LaTex before and I am struggling with Image placement when creating documents.  Specifically do the images have to be of a certain quality, size or format. Does Lyx support tranparency.  Maybe there are too many questions here and ultimately I am looking for somekind of user manual.

Background:
Im using Lyx because I am writing a book and want to present it in different formats (e.g. final format, manuscript etc).

Comment: Do you *have* to use LaTex?

Comment: No, I want to use Lyx only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Lyx is actually Latex in the background. Following from that is that guidelines for preparing images should be the same as for Latex.

The Lyx documentation can be found at http://wiki.lyx.org/

Specifically, the page about figures is at http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Figures

I have to say, though, this question should be moved to https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I had a quick scan at the link you sent and I believe my answers are in there. Thanks.  To your second point I will refer all future Lyx questions to the Tex stack exchange (unless they are technical issues).  I have been using the Ubuntu exchange a lot recently and saw Lyx as a tag which is why I posted here, thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, post either at tex.SE (where the probability that someone knows an answer is higher because the latex users are there), or at http://superuser.com for a general lyx question (they also have a a lyx tag there). askubuntu is more for ubuntu-related questions.